# Stabilizing output values of conductive sheet(Velostat) connected to analog pin A0 of Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, analogwrite

I am trying to do some experiments with conductive sheet (velostat). When I apply a force on the sheet it should change the value of resistance(output). I taking the output of the sheet by connecting to analog input Ao of Arduino. But I am not getting constant readings from arduino, even if no pressure is applied. Do I need to build any extra circuitry to stabilize the output value? Can anyone please tell how to stabilize the output value of Arduino?

Comment: Did you include a fixed resistor to form a voltage divider network with the velostat?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a matching resistance to create a voltage divider.

Comment: Could you put some more details on your answer? Maybe the OP does not know what a voltage divider is?

Comment: I am using 10k resisrtor to form a voltage divider circuit at the end